# Drop down in HTML table and have selected value in table data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, html-table

I have Dropdown in html Table

```
                <td contenteditable="true">
                                <select class="currentCulture form-control">

                             <option value="0" >1</option>
                             <option value="1" >2</option>
                            <option value="2" >3</option>

                                 </select>

                             </td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">Stir Fry</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">Stir Fry</td>
```

I return the whole data of HTML table to my controller in json form with ajax call

```
      var table = $('#datatable').tableToJSON();
        var datatosend = JSON.stringify(table)
            alert(JSON.stringify(table));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/SalesContracts/addd',
                data: datatosend,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                    alert('hii');
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
```

And getting Result like

```
   {[
     {

       "Brand": "1\n  2\n   3", 
        "Model": "Stir Fry",
        "Name": "stir-fry",
        "Quantity": "Stir Fry",
        "Unit": "stir-fry",
        "Price Cost": "Stir Fry",
        "SubTotal": "stir-fry",
         "": ""
```

}
]}

I am receiving all three options of select(Dropdown) "brand" I just want to get the selected one in Jsondata. Is there any possible solution for this?? . I will be thankfull if someone help me.Thank you.

**TableTojson Method**

```
    (function(e){e.fn.tableToJSON=function(t){var n={ignoreColumns:[],onlyColumns:null,ignoreHiddenRows:!0,headings:null};t=e.extend(n,t);var r=function(e){return e!==undefined&&e!==null?!0:!1},i=function(n){return r(t.onlyColumns)?e.inArray(n,t.onlyColumns)===-1:e.inArray(n,t.ignoreColumns)!==-1},s=function(t,n){var r={};return e.each(n,function(e,n){e<t.length&&(r[t[e]]=n)}),r},o=function(t){var n=[];return e(t).children("td,th").each(function(t,s){if(!i(t)){var o=e(s).data("override"),u=e.trim(e(s).text());n[n.length]=r(o)?o:u}}),n},u=function(e){var n=e.find("tr:first").first();return r(t.headings)?t.headings:o(n)},a=function(n,i){var u=[];return n.children("tbody,*").children("tr").each(function(n,a){if(n!==0||r(t.headings))if(e(a).is(":visible")||!t.ignoreHiddenRows)u[u.length]=s(i,o(a))}),u},f=u(this);return a(this,f)}})(jQuery);
```

IF there is another way to get tabledata with selected dropdown value please guide me to that.Thank you.

Comment: And what is this magical method: `tableToJSON`?

Comment: I have js library for convert whole table data to json form.

      <script src="~/Assets/js/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>

Comment: Well isn't that the code where you have the problem.....

Comment: So will you please guide me to better solution to get html table data in json with drop down selected value?.

Comment: You can use jQuery's serialize() method to collect form data, but it seems your table also has regular text you want to collect. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am getting data in right format.problem is that I am facing is I have brand dropdown in table row. I select value from it like I selected "2" 

       I should get data like 


              {[
     {

       "Brand": "1", 
       
} ]}




but I am getting all values of dropdown 


      {[
     {

       "Brand": "1\n  2\n   3", 
       
} ]}

Comment: I understand, but that seems to be a problem or limitation of your tableToJson plugin. I'd look into jQuery's serialize() method....

Comment: I have edited my answer you can see tableToJson method. Can you please guide me where things is going wrong?

Comment: The method called tableToJSON has a name that indicates it produces JSON *(which is a string)*. Why do you proceed to call JSON.stringify(table) afterwards?

Comment: Because If i doesn't do that i will unable to get data in controller. Even it will show nothing in alert box with just 
alert("table");

Comment: Hats Off for those who are marking my question negative. I think its legal one I have a problem if you can't solve it then why you are voting down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is will help you or may be this is not the optimized approach but it will do the job .
Can't you remove the not selected option and generate the json.

I have added a temp div and cloned the table and added to that

```
<div id="tempdiv" style="visibility:hidden">

$('#datatable').clone().appendTo($("#tempdiv"));
var tempTable=$("#tempdiv").children(0);
var sel = tempTable.find(".currentCulture");
$(sel).children().not("option:selected").remove();
```

`var table = (tempTable).tableToJSON();`

Comment: Ginish I am very thankful to you .I have one more question will you please tell me how to populate select tag options   <select > with ajax call

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: "/SalesContracts/get" ,
        datatype: 'json'
    })
  .done(function (data) {    
      var jdata = JSON.parse(data);    
      $.each(jdata, function (i, j) {       
         $('#sel_data').append($("<option>", {
            value: j.valuefield ,
            text: j.displayfield
        }));
         
      });      

  });